# How to assign participants to a study?

Tags: python, list, random, numbers

I want to be able to ask the user to input the number of participants in a sample size, and enter the maximum and minimum age of the participants. Next I want the code to randomly assign to **each** participant: gender (1 for male, 2 for female), and age of the participant. The program should then display the total number of male and female participants separately along with their average age.

I am a novice in Python so I have been searching up and down the web for how to assign the gender (1 or 2) to each number in the study. I can split the sample size into a list but I am confused on how to assign said value to each number, maybe I am just missing a simple function.

```
num = int(input('Enter the number of participants in the study: '))
max = int(input('Enter the maximum age of the participants: '))
min = int(input('Enter the minimum age of the participants: '))

x = list(range(num+1))
```

Comment: First create an emply `list`, then loop `for` the number of participants times, and each iteration `append()` a tuple to it containing randomly assigned age and sex values. You can generate random integer values using the [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this strategy, you can use the following code to achieve your output. Thanks!

```
from random import randint

num = int(input('Enter the number of participants in the study: '))
max = int(input('Enter the maximum age of the participants: '))
min = int(input('Enter the minimum age of the participants: '))
male = 0
female = 0
i = 0
li= list()
while i < num:
    age = randint(min, max)
    gender = ('male') if randint(1, 2) == 1 else 'female'
    li.append({gender:age})
    i= i+1

for i in li:
    if i.has_key('male'):
        male = male + 1
    else:
        female = female + 1
print(li)
print(male)
print(female)
```

Comment: The only problem I am having is that the number of participants in sample_dict does not match the number of participants entered. It only produces about half the participants entered give or take. Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: Just updated the code. It should work fine. Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much! One thing to point out, I don't think has_key works in the newest version of python. Instead "if 'male' in i:" works just fine :)